# Why int a = 5 - '0'; is possible in java?

Tags: java

```
   public static void main( String... args){
        int a = 5 - '0';
        System.out.println(a);  //-43
        Integer b = 5 - '0';
        System.out.println(b);  //-43
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(a)); //-43
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));  //-43
    }
```

So I have two questions for this code.

- Why `int=5-'0';` is possible?? `5` is an int which is ok but next to that is a character than why it's not throwing any error??
- Is it the ASCII value of result? than how result will be calculated?

I know ASCII value of `43` is `+` but is it will convert `'0'` to it's ASCII and then do the operation?

Comment: Because a character is a number.

Comment: simply have a look at a ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/  The ascii value of '0' is 48

Comment: It is because the character constant `'0'` is automatically promoted to an int in this context

Comment: @fge That is a dangerous simplification (because people could read it as if `'0'` gets converted to `0`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did say "character constant", I never said anything about it being a numeric literal :p

Comment: A char is simply an unsigned 16-bit number, it's basically an int derivate

Comment: '0' is considered  a char so it will be converted to int. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):
char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

In this case it is <del>casted</del> to int, that is why it works.
**Correction**
This is called [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). Thanks @Andreas!

+1 curiosity

```
  public static  void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5 - '0';
    }
```

I compiled this to bytecode:

```
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 24 L0
    BIPUSH -43
    ISTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 25 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE a I L1 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

Notice the line with  `BIPUSH -43` which means this value is calculated buildtime not runtime!

Comment: "Doc" != "specification". A doc can claim anything without consequence.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, the oracle nuts and bolts tutorials for sure are not "docs that claim anything".

Comment: @GhostCat Irrelevant. They _can_ claim anything and I spotted several times some inaccuracies. They are not normative and that's all there is to it.

Comment: @csenga which means at the build time by looking at the variable declaration(means int type) it will convert that to int or as always it will store char in ascii??

Comment: In this case it does not do compute anything runtime, it precalcualtes it buildtime.

Comment: @csenga is always java stores a char in its ASCII??

Comment: `5 - '0'` has no "cast". It does a Widening Primitive Conversion ([JLS §5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)).

Answer (score 2):

As described in [specification - data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/lexical.html#3.10.4), `char` represents a `UTF-16` code unit, which can range from `\u0000` to `\uffff`.

As described in [specification - integral types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1), `char` is an integral type, which means it can be converted to any other integral type. So, `\u0000` can be considered as `0` and `\uffff` can be considered as `65535`, both lies within `int` boundaries.

In an operation, operands are converted to biggest data type involved, so in,

```
int a = 5 - '0';
```

5 is an `int` which represents a bigger domain than `char`. So, `'0'` will be converted to `48`, and operation becomes:

```
int a = 5 - 48;  //i.e. -43
```

Answer (score 1):

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

The above quote is from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). It clearly says, that the minimum value of `char` is `0` and the maximum is `65,535`. Java provides casting from `char` to `int`.

According to the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:(...)
> For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Comment: Your "documentation" is nothing but an informative tutorial. You should quote the [_specification_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) for authoritative reference: `The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).)`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've added it to my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

By performing the `-` operation on an int and a char, the ascii value of the char is used (48 in your case). Hence the expression is transformed into:

```
int a = 5 - 48;
```